# Website optimization / decrease loading time in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: performance, asp.net-mvc-3, optimization, stack-trace

I have built a test website using nopCommerce open source , Everything is working fine , i need to know , why my website loading time is greater than 6 sec , the homepage works fine but the categories when clicked takes like 6-10 secs. how can i check the http request and calls to db so that i can track which function is taking a long times.

Test website is [test website](http://www.teamlemon.co.uk/)
Thanks

Comment: As Darin pointed out, the biggest problem is on the server, for sure. However, the frontend also shows some space for improvement of load times. Compression, caching, combining images into sprites and combining and minifying css and js, for example, will help. See https://developers.google.com/pagespeed/#url=http_3A_2F_2Fwww.teamlemon.co.uk_2Fc_2F7_2Frapid-assayspoc&mobile=false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Things I would try in that order:

- [MvcMiniProfiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/).
- Analyze my code for possible performance bottlenecks using a .NET profiler.
- Finally submit bugs to the nopCommerce support if the previous approaches didn't yield anything fruitful that would put my code into cause.

In between I might also checkout with my hosting provider whether he is not the cause of the slowness.

Comment: @MrA, yes, there's the CLR Profiler from Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx

Comment: more on e-commerce site performance check [this](http://www.quora.com/How-are-the-page-load-times-of-FlipKart-Myntra-and-Amazon-so-low-despite-the-many-images-of-large-sizes-too-on-the-websites?srid=hyI3&share=1) and [this](http://www.quora.com/What-can-I-do-to-make-my-asp-net-shopping-website-as-fast-as-Flipkart-Myntra-and-Amazon-with-hundreds-of-images-in-the-page), hope helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick and dirty check, you can add the time it takes to generate the response as a column in the IIS logs - that will give you some idea as to whether the server is being slow to serve the pages or you need to do some front-end optimisation work.

On the front end side the first thing you need to do it merge all the CSS files for a theme into one to save on roundtrips - the browser can't render the page until it's got the CSS

All the .js files you have in the head will also block the page, can you merge them and load them later?

The performance of imagegen.ashx looks on the slow side - do you need to generate the banners on the fly or could they be pre-generated?

If the back-end side of generating the page is slow, there are some scripts around the web to show which queries are using the most CPU, making the most IO ops etc.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a list of things you can improve,

1.Combine your js.

There are a few things you can use, for example, jsMin, you can read this [post] http://encosia.com/automatically-minify-and-combine-javascript-in-visual-studio/. However, jsmin doesn't seem to compress the combined js.

Another option is [jmerge] http://demo.lateralcode.com/jmerge/  It kinda does it after the fact, in the sense that you need to have the site ready to cobine them with jmerge since it only take a http link.

The best one I'v known so far is bundling and minification feature of MVC4. It's part of MVC4, however, you can get a Nuget package for you MVC 3 app.

Word of advice: bundling every js of yours is not necessarily a good idea, it even backfires someimtes, since you will end up with a big js that browser will have to download sequentially, instead of downloading several smaller ones. (you might want to look into head.js to make js download parallel) So the trick here is to keep the balance. I end up have a jquery from google CDN and bundled the rest of my js into one.

2.Put js at the bottom of the page so the browser doesnt have to load the js first before it starts to render the page. But you need to be careful with this one though, since normally you will have jquery functions doing stuff upon document.ready() at the header of the page, I adviese you moving that to the bottom of the page as well, if possible.

If you move the js reference and scirpt block in you layout page to the bottom, then you will most likely run into problem with nested js reference and js script blocks in your individual view. No worries, then you need to look into using @section (probably suitable for a discussion in an other thread) in your view and render it in your layout page, so that the referenced and script block inside your view get rendered at the bottom of the page at run time.

2.Use CDN
Pretty straight forward.

3.Combine CSS
Combine them into one, with the same tool you use for combining js, but you need to reference it at the page header, instead of the bottom.

4.Enable static content cache, something like this in your web config file

It won't help with first time load, but definitely will make it a lot faster for returning user.

5.Enable url compression

1. Time to first load
   This is one of the metrics used by webpagetest.org. But dont bang your head against this one too much, as it basically says how fast your web server can serve the content. So probably not much you can do here form the software end.

Hope that would help!

Answer (score 0):

NopCommerce is deadly slow, and the developers doesn't look in to the performance issue seriously. I have seen lot of performance related forums left unanswered. So best luck.

Comment: May be you can look at this performance plugin for nopcommerce here for help: http://www.nopaccelerate.com/

Comment: thanks, I'm already using this. It helped us fix all our speed and scalability issues. Thank you for your recommendation.